# SFML program doesn't find libGLEW

Tags: c++, compilation, sfml, glew

Recently I upgraded my **Ubuntu 13.10 to 14.04.** 
After that, I built **SFML 2.1** using **CMake**.

I downloaded and installed each and every package as asked on the **SFML-site**.
Compiling that program doesn't cause any errors, but as soon as I try to execute the program it says the following:

Compiling line:

`"g++ -o output character.cpp enemy.cpp gamehandler.cpp program.cpp -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system"`

<-- that still works, but if I try to execute it, the following happens:

```
"./output: error while loading shared libraries: libGLEW.so.1.8: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"
```

I then tried: 
**"apt-get install libglew-dev"**
which tells me that **"libglew-dev is already the newest verion."**

So my question is: What can I do about it, what do I do so it compiles again?

Comment: Did you update GLEW in between building SFML and building your application? What version of GLEW has been installed?

Comment: No I didn't update glew between building SFML.
I tried apt-get remove libglew-dev after it didn't work the first time and install it again, but it wouldn't change anything.

Comment: So it still remains the question: What version *is* installed on your system?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I wanted to answer my question earlier but had problems logging into stackoverflow.com.

However, I just removed SFML and reinstalled it again and it worked just fine, thanx for your help though!